# Printing out HTML tags from a string

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to print all the html tags that are contained inside a string. Something seems to be wrong with the logic of code here, I keep getting a never ending loop.

```
string fileLine;
string strToPush;

fileLine ="<html> sdad </b>as"; // My string that I want to find tags from

  cout << fileLine << '\n';

  while(!fileLine.length()==0)
  {

      if(fileLine.at(0)=='<')
        { 
            strToPush = "";
            while(!fileLine.at(0)=='>') 
            {
            strToPush = strToPush + fileLine.at(0);
            fileLine.erase (0); 
            }

            cout << endl << "HTML Tag detected: " << strToPush <<endl;

        }
        else
        {
        fileLine.erase (0);
        }
  }
```

Comment: You should use an HTML or XML parser, so you don't have to waste time debugging the functionality.

Comment: I suspect your issue lies in the comparisons involving `!` and `==`.

For example, your while loop... Did you really intend `!fileline.length() == 0`? Or maybe you really wanted `fileline.length() != 0` or even `!(fileline.length() == 0)`.

As you wrote it, `!fileline.length()` will be evaluated as true when the length is zero and false when the length is non-zero. Comparing true == 0 will be false, false == 0 will be true... Confusing, isn't it?

If you mean to check that the length is not zero, then use the not-equal operator:  `!=`

Comment: If all you want to do is search for the pattern `<[^<>]*>`, then regex could help.  But this will also report occurrences inside comments and not validate anything.  If you need more functionality, use a dedicated library as suggested above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are getting tripped by operator precedence. The line

```
while(!fileLine.length()==0)
```

is equivalent to

```
while( (!fileLine.length()) == 0 )
```

What you probably meant to do is:

```
while( !(fileLine.length() == 0) )
```

You can simplify that to:

```
while( !fileLine.empty() )
```

Similarly, change the line

```
while(!fileLine.at(0)=='>')
```

to

```
while ( fileLine.at(0) != '>' )
```

Comment: Also, the line: `while(!fileLine.at(0)=='>') ` will likely have similar issues.

Comment: That seemed to be the problem, also turns out I was using the erase() method improperly.